# Changing version of C++ for Visual Studio Code on M2 Macbook

Tags: c++17, homebrew, vs-code-settings

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code for C++. Usually I do this on my windows pc but I wanted to use my macbook instead so I could sit somewhere else and while following tutorials I've come across an issue where I made a file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

class Fraction{
    int m_numerator=0;
    int m_denominator=1;
    public:
        Fraction(int numerator=0, int denominator=1)
            : m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator) {
    
            reduce();
            }
            
        
        void reduce()
    {
        int gcd = std::gcd(m_numerator, m_denominator);
        if (gcd){
            m_numerator /= gcd;
            m_denominator /= gcd;
        }
    }

        friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2);
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Fraction& f1);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, Fraction& f1);
        
        void print(){
            std::cout << m_numerator << '/' << m_denominator << std::endl;
        }
};

Fraction operator*(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2){
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * f2.m_numerator , f1.m_denominator * f2.m_denominator);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Fraction& f1){
    out << f1.m_numerator << "/" << f1.m_denominator;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Fraction& f1){
    std::cout << "Enter the Numerator: ";
    in >> f1.m_numerator;
    std::cout << "Enter the Denominator: ";
    in >> f1.m_denominator;
    return in;
}


int main()
{

    Fraction f1;
    std::cin >> f1;
    Fraction f2;
    std::cin >> f2;

    std::cout << f1 << " * " << f2 << " = " << f1*f2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this same code on the windows pc using code runner it's fine but when I run it on the mac using code runner I get the following:

```
fraction.cpp:5:20: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int m_numerator=0;
                   ^
fraction.cpp:6:22: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int m_denominator=1;
                     ^
fraction.cpp:18:18: error: no member named 'gcd' in namespace 'std'
                int gcd = std::gcd(m_numerator, m_denominator);
                          ~~~~~^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

I have installed the latest version of Homebrew, installed the latest version of the LLVM, installed the Microsoft C/C++ Extension on VS Code and also installed Code runner.

below is what my c_cpp_properties.json file looks like. I would appreciate any help to try and fix this issue so I'm able to run the code on my mac the same way as I can on my windows pc. Thank you

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This is tasks.json

```
    {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Changed the version of C++ in the json file settings hoping that it would recognise this and allow the program to run.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is used for IntelliSense. You need to modify `tasks.json` and add the following to the `args` array: `-std=c++17`

Comment: I did already have "args": [
                "-std=c++17" added to tasks.json but the issue still persists unfortunately.

Comment: AFAIK Code Runner does not use that "tasks.json", it instead executes build commands directly. You probably need to add the `-std=c++17` to the Code Runner configuration (the executor map): https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration

Comment: It seems while searching I found this https://isbhargav.github.io/posts/How-to-setup-vscode/ and it is exactly as you said! Thank you so much for your comments both of you.